# SQL statement for minimum time and minimum ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm really new to SQL, and I've encountered the problem as shown below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkmv.png]

Imagine this person has made payments at the respective timings, with the respective IDs.

I would like to find out the amount of the earliest payment. If there are multiple entries for the earliest date, I would want to choose the entry with the smallest payment ID.

In this image the answer is simple, but what if the earliest payment was done on 5 Apr?

After removing the blank spaces for the titles, and after searching high and low for the answers, I wrote this:

```
SELECT PaymentID, PaymentAmt 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        MIN(s.PaymentID), 
        s.PaymentDate, 
        s.PaymentAmt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.PaymentID ORDER BY s.PaymentDate) rn 
    FROM sheetName s 
    GROUP BY s.userid, s.PaymentDate, s.PaymentAmt
) t 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

And it still doesn't work.

Could anyone help me with this?

EDIT: As written in my reply to Mark, what if I am looking into a group of people instead? So there could be another person with a different "userID" with their set of payment IDs and etc. If I want to find out the earliest payment amount for each person, what would be a good solution?

Comment: If you need to partition by something like "userID", use Squirrel's answer but add `PARTITION BY userID` in the row number window function.

Comment: That second is another question - especially since you will want new/different answers, post each table and what you have tried.  Post all the details (tables) and what you have tried in that new question

Answer (score 4):

Why make it complicated?

```
SELECT TOP 1 PaymentID, PaymentAmt
FROM sheetName
ORDER BY s.PaymentDate ASC, s.PaymentID ASC
```

Comment: NOTE: there is no way with the data provided to join with a person but for the data you provided this should work

Comment: IF you just need a date, add that WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Here's another question: What if I am actually dealing with multiple people? So let's say I add another column "user ID". And I want to find out the earliest payment amount for each person.

In that case, SELECT TOP 1 doesn't seem to work anymore. Do you have a solution that takes this into account?

It's an extension to the question, would be glad if you can help out on this one too!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Btw, thanks a lot, I didn't know that you could "ORDER BY" more than one column.

Comment: re: another column/table - that is another question regarding JOIN - please post another question for that as this one has several answers now.  Please then give the layout (columns) of each table along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple users, perhaps something like this -

```
select s.userid, s.paymentid, s.paymentdate, s.paymentamt
from sheetname s inner join
(
    select t.userid, min(t.paymentid) as minid
    from sheetname t inner join 
    (
        select u.userid, min(u.paymentdate) as mindate
        from sheetname u
        group by u.userid
    ) v on t.userid = v.userid and t.paymentdate = v.mindate
    group by t.userid
) w on s.userid = w.userid and s.paymentid = w.minid
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `row_number()` with `order by PaymentDate, PaymentID`

```
select *
from
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (order by PaymentDate, PaymentID)
    from   sheetName
) d
where d.rn = 1
```